# Unable to create call, trying to fetch my firebase database into recyclerview via retrofit

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, retrofit

Had trouble even finding some useful resources on Firebase+Retrofit (contrary to overpopulated tutorials on other aspects of Android). First time using Firebase, i've imported a json:

```
{"Qoutes" :[
   {
      "quote":"I\u2019m sure you are tired counting the years of your age. May these years be endless and full of happiness!",
      "relation":"grandmother"
   },
   {
      "quote":"My sweet Grandma, I wish you to be always happy and healthy as today! Happy birthday my beloved old woman!",
      "relation":"grandmother"
   },
   {
      "quote":"May you stay healthy and happy for the years to come. We are all happy to have you here with us!",
      "relation":"grandmother"
   },
.
.
.
]}
```

Wish class

```
data class Wish(
    @SerializedName("quote")
    val quote: String?,
    @SerializedName("relation")
    val relation: String?
)
```

APIService interface

```
interface APIService {

    @GET("Qoutes")
    suspend fun getQuotes(): Response<Wish>

}
```

RetrofitInstance

```
object RetrofitInstance {

    private val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://birthdayzheimer-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    val api: APIService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
    }

}
```

Repository

```
class Repository @Inject constructor() {

    suspend fun getWishes(): Response<Wish> {
        return RetrofitInstance.api.getQuotes()
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
private val repository: Repository
    ): ViewModel() {

    var myResponse: MutableLiveData<Response<Wish>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getQuotes() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response: Response<Wish> = repository.getWishes()
            myResponse.value = response
        }
    }
```

and the relevant part inside the fragment

```
viewModel.getQuotes()
        viewModel.myResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { response ->
            if(response.isSuccessful)
                Log.d("Response ->", response.body().toString())
            else
                Log.d("Response ->", response.errorBody().toString())
```

I hope that it's a noobish mistake somewhere as this is all fresh to me, and that it's not too bothersome to read all the classes. Thanks in advance to everyone reading.

P.s. i know i wrote quotes wrong in json, so i was consistent and wrote it wrongfully same everywhere else :D

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do here is access the Firebase Realtime Database through its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start). To make sure this works, you need to end the URL with `.json`

So:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://birthdayzheimer-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json")
```

Note that there might be multiple problems, but this is certainly one of them.